# Convert code of jquery in mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Please help to convert code of jquery to mootools.

I'm was not found clearable mootools plugin like jquery http://jsbin.com/sejuquta/528/edit.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 

  $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
  }).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');   
  }).on('click', '.onX', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
  });

});
```

I tried to rewrite this code to mootools, but I did not succeed (http://jsbin.com/wofaripi/1/edit).

```
window.addEvent("domready", function() {
  function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 
  $$('input[type=text]').addEvent('input', '.clearable', function(){
    this[tog(this.value)]('x');
  }).addEvent('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    this[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');   
  }).addEvent('click', '.onX', function(){
    this.removeClass('x onX').set('value', '');
  });

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think OP did make own effort to fix this problem and therefore should be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You managed a good way into the conversion.

Some notes:

#1 - Delegation looks a bit different in MooTools, you can read about it [here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation), but it should look like:

```
$(document.body).addEvent('input:relay(input.clearable)', function(){
```

#2 - I would remove the `tog` "thing". MooTools has a toggleClass method with a second function parameter "force" that does that and is more clear to read.

#3 - The add/remove class method in MooTools allows to add space separated classes but this is not documented, this not officially supported. So I did `this.removeClass('x').removeClass('onX')` instead od `this.removeClass('x onX');` which would also work, unofficially.

So, the code:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function () {

    $(document.body).addEvents({

        'input:relay(input.clearable)': function () {
            this.toggleClass('x', this.value);
        },

        'mousemove:relay(.x)': function (e) {
            this.toggleClass('onX', this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        },

        'click:relay(.onX)': function () {
            this.removeClass('x').removeClass('onX').set('value', '');
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92McL/

Comment: Thanks Sergio for your answer)

Comment: @AlexandrLunev please check it, I did by memory and did not test.

Comment: I'm a little corrected your code. Thank you Sergio!
http://jsbin.com/lojajape/1/edit